# Multiple Profiles in WabSphere Application server

Tags: java, windows, server, command-prompt

Can we create multiple default profiles in WabSphere Application server.
Also I want to know if I already have a default profile in  WAS and want to create another one through command prompt then by what command i can do so.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a new default profile. and yes It worked means we can create multiple default profiles on WAS
I tried below command -

```
c:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin\manageprofiles.bat -create -profileName AppSrv02 -profilePath C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv02 -templatePath C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profileTemplates\default  -enableAdminSecurity true -adminUserName wasadmin -adminPassword password  -winserviceAccountType localsystem -winserviceCheck true -winserviceStartupType automatic
```

***(if making a secured connection then add ->  -enableAdminSecurity true -adminUserName wasadmin -adminPassword password in above command)** 
It created a new Profile AppSrv02 and I was having another default profile AppSrv01.
The above command generated different admin console Port and request Port. 
So multiple default profiles can work in WabSphere Application server